# Create a single texture for an object that uses more than a texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking

I've scanned a little statue and made it into a 3D object using Meshroom. Because the software creates the textures from the images you provide, some of them are too big, and it splits them in 2 or more parts.

I've edited the model in Blender, and I cleaned the object to the point that only 1/4 of the initial textures are used and exported it as an obj. 
When I wanted to upload my object to sketchfab, I found out I can only select one of the two textures to apply it on the model.

When searching for a fix I have found some similar posts that pointed that baking the textures is the way to go, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, because when the model was imported, it created this complex node system for the textures (for each one) and when I unwrapped the model, some were corresponding to a texture and the others to the other texture, like in this pictures: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My question is, what should I do to create a single texture file, only with the parts that are used and how to replace the existing ones with the one that I make.**

Also, I'm sorry if this may seem like a stupid question for some of you, but I've just started working with textures, and it's proving to be a little more difficult than I thought...

Comment: Should be the same procedure as if you bake a high-poly mesh onto a low-poly mesh. Create a copy of your object, delete the material, create a new one (plain BSDF). Then create a new image in the UV/Image editor, add a new image texture node in the node editor and select the new image in the dropdown.. Select the original object, then shift-select the copy, and bake your new texture.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I got it working, but the new generated texture has some weird spots and it is a tad darker than the original. I suspect that it may be from the bake settings, but I don't know what to change. [Here is a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/d0nk96o).

Comment: Those spots might as well be scan errors. You can paint over them in Texture Paint mode (make a copy) and brighten the texture in Gimp or Photoshop.